# Best way to cut 3d text according to another surface

Tags: objects, text-object

apologies for the potentially basic question. I'm learning blender and finding it quite difficult to know what the best conventions are when trying to cut a mesh, specifically 3d text.

I have this 3d text on top of another cube mesh. I want to cut off the excess of the text so that the edges of the text and the edges of the underlying block are completely aligned, and the final result looks like a single unified object.

[image]

Conceptually I want to extrude the edges of the cube upwards and cut out any text that falls outside of the extruded faces (but obviously I don't want to see the faces in final render), and then join the cube and the text together.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to BSE,

I think a Boolean Modifier may be what you want, applied either to the Text object or the Cube object, depending on the results you want.

A Boolean Modifier combines one mesh object with another in a variety of ways, depending on the settings.

**Sample scene**

[image]

**Boolean Modifier applied to Text object, using Cube object as Target**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

*Note: The **Cube object** is **hidden** in the above images. Only the **Text object** is shown*

**Boolean Modifier applied to Cube object, using Text object as Target**

[image]

[image]

[[image][10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTeMw.png)

[image]

[image]

(Modifier applied. View from Edit Mode):

[image]

*Note: The **Text object** is **hidden** in the above images. Only the **Cube object** is shown*

I recommend experimenting with this modifier. Try not only adding the modifier to your Cube/Text object, but also **applying the modifier** (hover over the modifier with your mouse and press CTRL+A). I believe you should be able to find a way to achieve the affect you are looking for.